# How can I upload/download a file with python and log the time it takes in each operation?

Tags: python, upload, download

I am trying to make and ftp client to upload and download a file in python but I need to log the time each operation takes. Hope can I get help in this site. I saw some code here but it shows just how to upload/download but how can I know the time each operation takes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure the elapsed time by recording the current time before the up- or download, then calculating the number of seconds since the previous time-stamp after the operation:

```
import time

start = time.time()  # seconds since the UNIX epoch

# upload your file

elapsed = time.time() - start
```

where `elapsed` will then be a floating point value measuring seconds since the first `time.time()` call.

Demo:

```
>>> import time, random
>>> start = time.time()
>>> time.sleep(random.randrange(20))  # random amount of time to wait
>>> print time.time() - start
20.8919820786
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn for your answer I'm going to try out this code I'm new in python. I just take the code from this site to upload the file but I need to measure how long the upload/download process takes. Sorry for my english I'm not an native english speaker.